# How to test internal set from foreign lib?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have a response object from a foreign lib on which I react on:

```
// Comes from outside
public void ResultClass
{
    public bool Succedded { get; internal set; }
}
```

Now my method uses it and reacts on it:

```
public void Sut
{
    public void MethodToTest()
    {
        var result = foreignLib.Call();
        if (!result.Succeded)
        {
             throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

The foreignLib is mockable, it has a nice interface, but of course I want to return a result on my wished behaviour, so I can test if the exception is thrown:

```
public void Test
{
    public void MethodToTest_Exception()
    {

        // problem: how to mock the result
        foreignLibMock.Setup(x => x.Call())
                           .ReturnsAsync(new Result()
                           {
                                // Cant set the result here, so I can't controle the outcame and therefore I cant test it...
                           });
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume the interface returns the concrete type and not an abstraction?  Idea #1: if the return type is not sealed you should be able to use `new` to override it in a derived type and have the mock return that.  Idea #2: not ideal but reflection would work.

Comment: Yes, it is the concrete type without interface - I like the new idea, thanks! Could you maybe add an example?

Comment: I was too hasty with Idea #1; don't think it will work in your scenario.  Reflection is probably your best option: `Result result = new(); PropertyInfo pi = typeof(Result).GetProperty(nameof(Result.Succeeded))!; pi.SetValue(result, true);`

Comment: Did you consider creating a derived type from `ResultClass` and returning an instance of this new type?